# Finding back a simple SDE from its solution

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differentiation, calculus, stochastic-processes

I'm trying to self-learn Kurt Jacob's *Stochastic Processes for Physicists: Understanding Noisy Systems*. I've followed Chapter 3, where I saw how to derive that the solution to the SDE
$$
dx=\left(c+\frac{b^2}{2} \right) xdt+bxdW 
$$
where $W$ is a Wiener process, is
$$
x(t) = x(0)\mathrm{e}^{ct+bW(t)}.
$$

I have a problem going in the reverse direction, i.e. computing the differential of $x$ from the solution. What I tried is:

\begin{align*}
dx &= \frac{\partial x}{\partial t}dt + \frac{\partial x}{\partial W}dW + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^{2} x}{\partial W^{2}}dt \\
\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}dt &= 
e^{ct+bW(t)} \left(c+b \frac{dW}{dt}\right)dt=cxdt+bxdW \\
\frac{\partial x}{\partial W}dW &= 
e^{ct+bW(t)}bdW = bxdW \\
\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^{2} x}{\partial W^{2}}dt &= 
\frac{1}{2}b^{2}xdt
\end{align*}

So all together
$$
dx = \left(c+ \frac{b^{2}}{2}\right)xdt + 2bxdW.
$$
So clearly I misunderstood how to handle $\frac{\partial W}{\partial t}dt$, and why it should be zero.

Comment: The errors are in
$$
\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}dt = 
e^{ct+bW(t)} \left(c+b \color{red}{\frac{dW}{dt}}\right)dt=cx\,dt+\color{red}{bx\,dW}
$$
You cannot differentiate the Wiener process. Drop those terms and it should work. Look at $x$ as a function of $t$ and $W_t$ separately and take its partial derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}$
As pointed out in the comments, the problem is that the [Wiener process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process) isn't really a function of time (instead is a process *indexed* at times $t$), so when applying the time-derivative to $x(t,\,W)$, we should find:
$$ \frac{\dd x}{\dd t}=\exp(xt+bW)\cdot\frac{\dd}{\dd t}\left(ct+bW\right)=c\cdot x(t). $$
which would result in an Ito equation of the form,
$$\dd x=cx\,\dd t+bx\,\dd W+\frac{1}{2}b^2x\,\dd t.$$

Note also that this SDE is the well-known [geometric Brownian motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion) and is possibly one of the most studied SDEs we have (I imagine the [OU process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process) might be give a run for its money, however). It is worth your time investing

Comment: Sorry for bringing this up again so late, but I happened to think about it again. I don't feel this answer (nor the other comment) really helped me understand it better. To my question of why the time derivative of $W$ is zero, the answer "the Wiener process isn't really a function of time (instead is a process indexed at times $t$)" feels like "it just is". I don't see the distinction between a function of time or indexed by time. As far as I understand, they are the same by definition: for each realization, $W(t)$ or $W_t$ is a mapping from time to values the Wiener process takes. Thanks

Comment: Usually one doesn't actually care about $W_t$ (or if you want, $W(t)$). Usually the interest is that $W_{t+\mathrm{d}t}-W_t\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\,\mathrm{d}t)$ (i.e., the increments are normally distributed with 0 mean and variance $\mathrm{d}t$) and, in your case, that it is nowhere differentiable (though that doesn't stop people from "defining" white noise as $\xi(t)=\mathrm{d}W/\mathrm{d}t$, though this is more an idealization).

Comment: In regards to nowhere differentiable, see for instance [this quant.se post](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/10861/how-can-the-wiener-process-be-nowhere-differentiable-but-still-continuous)